# Joining 3 mysql tables w/queries in between

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I'm attempting to join 3 tables - `e`, `wp`, `l`

locations as l : `name | id | workplace_id`

workplaces as wp : `name | id`

employees as e : `name | id | location_id | coordinator`

I want to:
**if a WORKPLACE has a COORDINATOR (coordinator=1) at any LOCATION
get all LOCATIONs for that WORKPLACE**

This doesn't seem to be working - it is returning all locations for the workplace that have a coordinator=1, but I need all location for a workplace if any of the workplaces locations has a coordinator=1.

```
select distinct w.* 
from workplaces as w, 
    (select distinct l.* 
     from locations as l, employees as e 
     where e.location_id = l.id and e.coordinator = 1) as tmp 
where tmp.workplace_id = w.id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select distinct l.* 
from locations as l, workplaces as w, 
    (select distinct l.* 
     from locations as l, employees as e 
     where e.location_id = l.id and e.coordinator = 1) as tmp 
where l.workplace_id = w.id
and tmp.workplace_id = w.id
```

Is that what you're looking for ?

Answer (score -1):

First of all subqueries is a really bad idea, and for making joins you should use any of these: inner join, left join, or right join. Then you can have something like this:

```
SELECT l.* FROM locations as l
INNER JOIN workplaces w ON l.workplace_id = w.id
INNER JOIN employees e ON l.id = e.location_id
WHERE e.coordinator = 1;
```